# How can move error in Alert to each form input when user input wrong

Tags: reactjs, validation, warnings

I am doing validation for form, but I have show error in alert not put it in each form, how can I move error in Alert to each form input when user input wrong

```
const onSave = (event) => {
    const invalid = [];
    ["name", "description"].forEach(key => {
      const value = (typeof values[key] === "number")
        ? values[key].toString()
        : values[key];

      if (value.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
        alert("Not allow number here");
      }
    });
    if (values.name.trim() === "") {
      alert("Please not left blank form");
    }
    if (invalid.length !== 0) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    // Only push to firebase when there are no errors
    if (invalid.length === 0) {
      createProductRequest(values, imageAsFile);
    }
  };
```

This is my form, where the user input fields

```
<Form.Group controlId="name">
          <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter product name"
            value={values.name}
            name="name"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="categories">
          <Form.Label>Categories</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            as="select"
            name="category"
            value={values.category}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          >
            {CATEGORIES.map((category) => (
              <option key={category}>{category}</option>
            ))}
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="price">
          <Form.Label>Price</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="number"
            placeholder="Enter product price"
            value={values.price}
            name="price"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="description">
          <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            as="textarea"
            rows="3"
            name="description"
            value={values.description}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>
```

I would like to these error in alert will show in each error field of the form. Anyone can help or support me, how can I move the error form in FormGroup instead of the alert above.

Thank you so much, I always welcome any answer all of you.

Comment: It would be easy to test this out if you could provide a codesandbox.

Comment: Looks like you're using react-bootstrap. You can use https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation